Can we find a product of single-qubit states that is orthogonal to a stabilizer codespace?
Let's consider a single-qubit pure state
$$\rho=\rho(x, y,z)=\frac{1}{2}(I+xX+yY+zZ)$$
with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.
Can we show the following statement is true: For any $n$-qubit tensor product states $\rho^{\otimes n}$ with $xyz\neq 0$, We cannot find a $n$-qubit stabilizer code $Q$ (with codespace projector $P_Q$), such that the $\rho^{\otimes n}$ is orthogonal to the codespace of $Q$.
Alternatively, my conjecture can be understood as
$$
Tr[P_Q\rho^{\otimes n}]>0  \ \ \forall  Q\in\{\text{stabilizer codes}\} \ \ \text{and} \ \  \forall\rho \in\{\rho(x,y,z): xyz\neq0\}.
$$
My intuition why this is true
For me, stabilizer codes can be understand as a tidy Clifford way to divide the whole $n$-qubit Hilbert spaces into several subspaces. However, the tensor product of general single-qubit states when $xyz\neq0$ are not "tidy", and therefore cannot be divided tidily.
When coordinates can be zero
Say $\rho=|0\rangle\langle 0|$. We can easily verify that $|0\rangle\langle 0|^{\otimes 3}$ is orthogonal to the codespace of the modified three-qubit repetition code with
$$
S=\{-Z_1Z_2, -Z_1Z_3\}
$$

How many independent generators should $S$ have? Is it $n-1$?

@rnva the # of stabilizer generators only need to be smaller than or equal to $n$.

Why do yu think $xyz\neq0$ plays a role? That is purely dependent on the choice of the basis, i.e. the operators $X, Y$ and$Z$, while the rest of your description does not rely on the choice of basis.

@JosBergervoet Assuming the stabilizers are tensor products of Paulis, that fixes the equivalent notion for $Q$, so that makes those states $xyz=0$ special being (for example) eigenstates of some terms.

TL;DR: I prove that, under certain additional assumptions, if $\mathrm{tr}(P_C\rho)=0$ for any $\rho(x,y,z)$ with $xyz\ne 0$, then $C$ fails to correct single-qubit errors. The additional assumptions I make (and which further work may be able to remove) are: every stabilizer acts as identity on at least one qubit and the matrix $M(C,\rho)$ defined in $(6)$ is non-singular. I also make the usual assumption that logical Pauli operators are selected from the $n$-qubit Pauli group.
Notation
Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the stabilizer group of the code $C$ and suppose that
\begin{align}
\rho(x,y,z)=|\psi(x,y,z)\rangle\langle\psi(x,y,z)|.\tag1
\end{align}
Following the convention in the question, I will suppress Bloch sphere coordinates when they are unimportant. In particular, $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$.
Inner products and Pauli action on $|\psi\rangle$
A non-identity Pauli operator sends $|\psi\rangle$ to a state of the form $|\psi(\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)\rangle$ where two coordinates have their signs flipped. We can calculate the absolute value of the inner product of two such states as follows
\begin{align}
|\langle\psi|Z|\psi\rangle|^2&=|\langle\psi(-x,-y,z)|\psi(x,y,z)\rangle|^2\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(\rho(-x,-y,z)\rho(x,y,z))\\
&=\frac12(1-x^2-y^2+z^2)\\&=z^2\in(0,1)\tag2
\end{align}
and similarly for other Pauli operators. Thus, distinct states of the form $|\psi(\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)\rangle$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal. This generalizes to the $n$-qubit state $|\psi\rangle^{\otimes n}$ and any $n$-qubit non-identity Pauli operator $p$ as
\begin{align}
|\langle\psi|^{\otimes n}p|\psi\rangle^{\otimes n}|^2=x^{2\mathrm{wt}_x(p)}y^{2\mathrm{wt}_y(p)}z^{2\mathrm{wt}_z(p)}\in(0,1)\tag3
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{wt}_x(p)$ is the number of qubits on which $p$ acts as Pauli $X$ and similarly for $Y$ and $Z$. Thus, $\langle\psi|^{\otimes n}p|\psi\rangle^{\otimes n}=e^{i\theta}x^{\mathrm{wt}_x(p)}y^{\mathrm{wt}_y(p)}z^{\mathrm{wt}_z(p)}$ for some phase angle $\theta$. If $p$ is Hermitian, then $\theta\in\left\{0,\pi\right\}$.
Linear independence of $\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle$
Next, we would like to show that the set $\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle$ of $2^{n-k}$ states $p_j|\psi\rangle$ for $p_j\in\mathcal{S}$ is linearly independent. Assume that
\begin{align}
\sum_ja_jp_j|\psi\rangle=0.\tag4
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\langle\psi|p_i\sum_ja_jp_j|\psi\rangle=\sum_ja_je^{i\theta_j}x^{\mathrm{wt}_x(p_ip_j)}y^{\mathrm{wt}_y(p_ip_j)}z^{\mathrm{wt}_z(p_ip_j)}=0\tag5
\end{align}
for all $i$ and some $\theta_j\in\left\{0,\pi\right\}$. Define the $2^{n-k}\times 2^{n-k}$ matrix $M(C,\rho)$ by setting the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column to
\begin{align}
M_{ij}:=x^{\mathrm{wt}_x(p_ip_j)}y^{\mathrm{wt}_y(p_ip_j)}z^{\mathrm{wt}_z(p_ip_j)}\tag6
\end{align}
where $s_i$ is the $i$th operator in the stabilizer group of $C$. For example, for the $[\![4,2,2]\!]$ code $C_4$ and the $T$-magic state $\tau=\rho\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)$ the matrix takes the form
\begin{align}
M(C_4, \tau)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac19 & \frac19 & \frac19\\
\frac19 & 1& \frac19 & \frac19\\
\frac19 & \frac19 & 1& \frac19\\
\frac19 & \frac19 & \frac19 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\tag7
\end{align}
which is strictly diagonally dominant with positive diagonal entries and hence positive definite. By contrast, if $\rho$ is stabilized by an operator in $\mathcal{S}$, then $M(C,\rho)$ is rank-deficient.
Code subspace is the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle$
We now assume that $M(C,\rho)$ is non-singular. We can rewrite $(5)$ as
\begin{align}
M(C,\rho)\,a=0\tag8
\end{align}
where $a=[a_1e^{i\theta_1},\dots,a_{2^{n-k}}e^{i\theta_{2^{n-k}}}]^T$. But if $M(C,\rho)$ is non-singular, we have $a=0$ and the states $\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle$ are linearly independent.
By assumption, $|\psi\rangle$ and $P_C$ are orthogonal. But for any $p\in\mathcal{S}$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(P_C|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\mathrm{tr}(pP_Cp|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\mathrm{tr}(P_Cp|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|p)\tag9
\end{align}
so $\mathrm{tr}(P_C\rho)=0$ implies that $P_C$ is orthogonal not only to $|\psi\rangle$, but to the entire subspace spanned by the set $\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle$. Moreover, the dimension of $P_C$ is $2^k$ and the dimension of $\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle)$ is $2^{n-k}$, so
\begin{align}
P_C=\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{S}|\psi\rangle)^\perp.\tag{10}
\end{align}
Failure of error correction
Finally, let $|\psi^\perp\rangle=|\psi(-x,-y,-z)\rangle$ and consider the state $|\psi^{\perp\otimes n}\rangle$. Assuming that every $p\in\mathcal{S}$ acts as identity on some qubit, we have $|\psi^{\perp\otimes n}\rangle\in P_C$. But this means that we can construct a weight-$1$ logical operator, so the code has distance one. For example, suppose that we chose $|0_L\rangle:=|\psi^{\perp\otimes n}\rangle$. If the logical operators are selected from the $n$-qubit Pauli group, then $|1_L\rangle$ is also a product state. However, then we can construct the logical $Z_L$ as a weight-$1$ operator acting on any one of the qubits on which $|0_L\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle$ are orthonormal.

Thank you Adam for providing the partial answer and it's very close to what I want!

You're welcome! Thank you for the kind words and for posting an interesting problem :-)
